# Pretty Printing a Binary tree - Converting from C++ to Java

Tags: java, c++, tree, binary-tree, pretty-print

Can someone please help implement the code in [this website](http://www.ihas1337code.com/2010/09/how-to-pretty-print-binary-tree.html) in Java based on the following class as the Node class:

```
public class Node<A extends Comparable<A>> {
Node<A> left, right;
A data;

public Node(A data){
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

The code is for pretty printing binary trees:

```
    #include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

struct BinaryTree {
  BinaryTree *left, *right;
  int data;
  BinaryTree(int val) : left(NULL), right(NULL), data(val) { }
};

// Find the maximum height of the binary tree
int maxHeight(BinaryTree *p) {
  if (!p) return 0;
  int leftHeight = maxHeight(p->left);
  int rightHeight = maxHeight(p->right);
  return (leftHeight > rightHeight) ? leftHeight + 1: rightHeight + 1;
}

// Convert an integer value to string
string intToString(int val) {
  ostringstream ss;
  ss << val;
  return ss.str();
}

// Print the arm branches (eg, /    \ ) on a line
void printBranches(int branchLen, int nodeSpaceLen, int startLen, int nodesInThisLevel, const deque<BinaryTree*>& nodesQueue, ostream& out) {
  deque<BinaryTree*>::const_iterator iter = nodesQueue.begin();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel / 2; i++) {
    out << ((i == 0) ? setw(startLen-1) : setw(nodeSpaceLen-2)) << "" << ((*iter++) ? "/" : " ");
    out << setw(2*branchLen+2) << "" << ((*iter++) ? "\\" : " ");
  }
  out << endl;
}

// Print the branches and node (eg, ___10___ )
void printNodes(int branchLen, int nodeSpaceLen, int startLen, int nodesInThisLevel, const deque<BinaryTree*>& nodesQueue, ostream& out) {
  deque<BinaryTree*>::const_iterator iter = nodesQueue.begin();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++, iter++) {
    out << ((i == 0) ? setw(startLen) : setw(nodeSpaceLen)) << "" << ((*iter && (*iter)->left) ? setfill('_') : setfill(' '));
    out << setw(branchLen+2) << ((*iter) ? intToString((*iter)->data) : "");
    out << ((*iter && (*iter)->right) ? setfill('_') : setfill(' ')) << setw(branchLen) << "" << setfill(' ');
  }
  out << endl;
}

// Print the leaves only (just for the bottom row)
void printLeaves(int indentSpace, int level, int nodesInThisLevel, const deque<BinaryTree*>& nodesQueue, ostream& out) {
  deque<BinaryTree*>::const_iterator iter = nodesQueue.begin();
  for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++, iter++) {
    out << ((i == 0) ? setw(indentSpace+2) : setw(2*level+2)) << ((*iter) ? intToString((*iter)->data) : "");
  }
  out << endl;
}

// Pretty formatting of a binary tree to the output stream
// @ param
// level  Control how wide you want the tree to sparse (eg, level 1 has the minimum space between nodes, while level 2 has a larger space between nodes)
// indentSpace  Change this to add some indent space to the left (eg, indentSpace of 0 means the lowest level of the left node will stick to the left margin)
void printPretty(BinaryTree *root, int level, int indentSpace, ostream& out) {
  int h = maxHeight(root);
  int nodesInThisLevel = 1;

  int branchLen = 2*((int)pow(2.0,h)-1) - (3-level)*(int)pow(2.0,h-1);  // eq of the length of branch for each node of each level
  int nodeSpaceLen = 2 + (level+1)*(int)pow(2.0,h);  // distance between left neighbor node's right arm and right neighbor node's left arm
  int startLen = branchLen + (3-level) + indentSpace;  // starting space to the first node to print of each level (for the left most node of each level only)

  deque<BinaryTree*> nodesQueue;
  nodesQueue.push_back(root);
  for (int r = 1; r < h; r++) {
    printBranches(branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);
    branchLen = branchLen/2 - 1;
    nodeSpaceLen = nodeSpaceLen/2 + 1;
    startLen = branchLen + (3-level) + indentSpace;
    printNodes(branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);

    for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++) {
      BinaryTree *currNode = nodesQueue.front();
      nodesQueue.pop_front();
      if (currNode) {
          nodesQueue.push_back(currNode->left);
          nodesQueue.push_back(currNode->right);
      } else {
        nodesQueue.push_back(NULL);
        nodesQueue.push_back(NULL);
      }
    }
    nodesInThisLevel *= 2;
  }
  printBranches(branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);
  printLeaves(indentSpace, level, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);
}

int main() {
  BinaryTree *root = new BinaryTree(30);
  root->left = new BinaryTree(20);
  root->right = new BinaryTree(40);
  root->left->left = new BinaryTree(10);
  root->left->right = new BinaryTree(25);
  root->right->left = new BinaryTree(35);
  root->right->right = new BinaryTree(50);
  root->left->left->left = new BinaryTree(5);
  root->left->left->right = new BinaryTree(15);
  root->left->right->right = new BinaryTree(28);
  root->right->right->left = new BinaryTree(41);

  cout << "Tree pretty print with level=1 and indentSpace=0\n\n";
  // Output to console
  printPretty(root, 1, 0, cout);

  cout << "\n\nTree pretty print with level=5 and indentSpace=3,\noutput to file \"tree_pretty.txt\".\n\n";
  // Create a file and output to that file
  ofstream fout("tree_pretty.txt");
  // Now print a tree that's more spread out to the file
  printPretty(root, 5, 0, fout);

  return 0;
}
```

http://www.ihas1337code.com/2010/09/how-to-pretty-print-binary-tree.html

Comment: So what have you tried so far?  What specific problems are you having?

Comment: Can you explain better which are your objectives after executing this code? What are problems with your tries? You need to help the community to help you. Copy&Paste a full code without issue directions can't aggregate anything to systems.

Comment: I'm having trouble with the methods like setw or setfill

Comment: The setw and setfill methods in the code you linked to have nothing to do with the binary tree. They're C++ standard-library things for manipulating an output stream. setw controls the number of characters to use for the next thing output to the stream. setfill controls what character will be used to fill up the difference between the number of characters actually needed for that thing, and the number setw said to use.

Comment: Java I/O doesn't work at all the same way; one reasonable alternative would be to make your pretty-printer generate a string; define a class whose only job is pretty-printing trees, and give it a StringBuilder and some fields that store the same information as setw and setfill are implicitly controlling in the C++ ostream. (The main reason for sending output to a stream rather than generating a string is because that can scale better when the output is huge, but I can't see this sort of pretty-printing being any use in that case anyway.)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a direct replacement for the setw and setfill methods in Java. However you can create a new object that wraps a PrintStream and adds the required padding when you write some output. For example:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class PaddedWriter {
    private int width = 0;
    private char fillChar = ' ';
    private final PrintStream writer;
    public PaddedWriter(PrintStream writer) {
        this.writer = writer;
    }
    void setw(int i) {
        width = i;
    }
    void setfill(char c) {
        fillChar = c;
    }
    void write(String str) {
        write(str.toCharArray());
    }
    void write(char[] buf) {
        if (buf.length < width) {
            char[] pad = new char[width - buf.length];
            Arrays.fill( pad, fillChar );
            writer.print(pad);
        }
        writer.print( buf );
        setw(0);
    }
    void write() {
        char[] pad = new char[width];
        Arrays.fill( pad, fillChar );
        writer.print(pad);
        setw(0);
    }
    void endl() {
        writer.println();
        setw(0);
    }
}
```

Using the PaddedWriter class it is possible to reimplement the code from http://www.ihas1337code.com/2010/09/how-to-pretty-print-binary-tree.html as follows:

```
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;


public class BinaryTree<T> {
    final T data;
    BinaryTree<T> left;
    BinaryTree<T> right;
    public BinaryTree(T t) {
        data  = t;
    }

    public void setLeft(BinaryTree<T> t) {
        left = t;
    }
    public void setRight(BinaryTree<T> t) {
        right = t;
    }

    public BinaryTree<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }
    public BinaryTree<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (data == null) {
            return "null";
        } else {
            return data.toString();
        }
    }


    // Search for the deepest part of the tree
    private static <T>int maxHeight(BinaryTree<T> t) {
        if (t == null)  return 0;
        int leftHeight = maxHeight( t.getLeft() );
        int rightHeight = maxHeight( t.getRight() );
        return (leftHeight > rightHeight) ? leftHeight+1: rightHeight+1;
    }

    // Pretty formatting of a binary tree to the output stream
    public static <T>void printPretty(BinaryTree<T> tree, int level, int indentSpace, PaddedWriter out) {
        int h = maxHeight( tree );
        int nodesInThisLevel = 1;
        int branchLen = 2*((int)Math.pow( 2.0, h )-1) - (3-level) *(int)Math.pow( 2.0, h-1 );
        int nodeSpaceLen = 2+(level+1)*(int)Math.pow(2.0,h);
        int startLen = branchLen + (3-level) + indentSpace;

        Deque<BinaryTree<T>> nodesQueue = new LinkedList<BinaryTree<T>>();
        nodesQueue.offerLast( tree );
        for (int r = 1; r < h; r++) {
            printBranches( branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out );
            branchLen = branchLen/2 - 1;
            nodeSpaceLen = nodeSpaceLen/2 + 1;
            startLen = branchLen + (3-level) + indentSpace;
            printNodes(branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++) {
                BinaryTree<T> currNode = nodesQueue.pollFirst();
                if (currNode!=null) {
                    nodesQueue.offerLast( currNode.getLeft() );
                    nodesQueue.offerLast( currNode.getRight() );
                } else {
                    nodesQueue.offerLast( null );
                    nodesQueue.offerLast( null );
                }
            }
            nodesInThisLevel *= 2;
        }
        printBranches(branchLen, nodeSpaceLen, startLen, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);
        printLeaves(indentSpace, level, nodesInThisLevel, nodesQueue, out);
    }

    private static <T>void printBranches(int branchLen, int nodeSpaceLen, int startLen, int nodesInThisLevel, Deque<BinaryTree<T>> nodesQueue, PaddedWriter out) {
        Iterator<BinaryTree<T>> iterator = nodesQueue.iterator();
        for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel/2; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                out.setw(startLen-1);
            } else {
                out.setw(nodeSpaceLen-2);
            }
            out.write();
            BinaryTree<T> next = iterator.next();
            if (next != null) {
                out.write( "/" );
            } else {
                out.write(" ");
            }
            out.setw(2*branchLen+2);
            out.write();
            next = iterator.next();
            if (next != null) {
                out.write( "\\" );
            } else {
                out.write( " " );
            }
        }
        out.endl();
    }

    // Print the branches and node (eg, ___10___ )
    private static <T>void printNodes(int branchLen, int nodeSpaceLen, int startLen, int nodesInThisLevel, Deque<BinaryTree<T>> nodesQueue, PaddedWriter out) {
        Iterator<BinaryTree<T>> iterator = nodesQueue.iterator();
        BinaryTree<T> currentNode;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++) {
            currentNode = iterator.next();
            if (i == 0) {
                out.setw(startLen );
            } else {
                out.setw(nodeSpaceLen );
            }
            out.write();
            if (currentNode != null && currentNode.getLeft() != null) {
                out.setfill( '_' );
            } else {
                out.setfill( ' ' );
            }
            out.setw( branchLen+2 );
            if (currentNode != null) {
                out.write(currentNode.toString());
            } else {
                out.write();
            }
            if (currentNode != null && currentNode.getRight() != null) {
                out.setfill( '_' );
            } else {
                out.setfill( ' ' );
            }
            out.setw(branchLen);
            out.write();
            out.setfill(' ');
        }
        out.endl();
    }

    // Print the leaves only (just for the bottom row)
    private static <T>void printLeaves(int indentSpace, int level, int nodesInThisLevel, Deque<BinaryTree<T>> nodesQueue, PaddedWriter out) {
        Iterator<BinaryTree<T>> iterator = nodesQueue.iterator();
        BinaryTree<T> currentNode;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodesInThisLevel; i++) {
            currentNode = iterator.next();
            if (i == 0) {
                out.setw(indentSpace+2);
            } else {
                out.setw(2*level+2);
            }
            if (currentNode !=null) {
                out.write(currentNode.toString());
            } else {
                out.write();
            }
        }
        out.endl();
    }

}
```

It can be tested with this class:

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {

        BinaryTree<Integer> root = new BinaryTree<Integer>(30);
        root.setLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>(20));
        root.setRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>(40));
        root.getLeft().setLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>(10));
        root.getLeft().setRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>(25));
        root.getRight().setLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>(35));
        root.getRight().setRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>(50));
        root.getLeft().getLeft().setLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>(5));
        root.getLeft().getLeft().setRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>(15));
        root.getLeft().getRight().setRight(new BinaryTree<Integer>(28));
        root.getRight().getRight().setLeft(new BinaryTree<Integer>(41));


        BinaryTree.printPretty( root, 1, 0, new PaddedWriter( System.out ) );
    }



}
```

Something that you might want to take into account if you use this code is that the width of the node is not taken into account when working out the spacing. So if you have add a node containing 123456789 it will not print nicely.